# JC dailies in MoP?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Does MoP have any JC (jewel crafting) dailies like Cataclysm? If so, who offers the dailies and where is he located?

The reason I ask is because I just hit 590 with my JC, but he's only level 86 and is still in the Jade Forest. Assuming that there are JC dailies in MoP, I would like to know where to go to get them, or if it's even possible to get them at my current level (do I have to be 90?).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no longer any jewelcrafting daily quests in Mists of Pandaria. It is instead replaced by daily researches that trigger a cooldown that resets at midnight server time. There are six researches you can do with 3 gems of your chosen colour, each giving you a recipe of the corresponding colour.

These are:

- [River's Heart](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=131593)
- [Imperial Amethyst](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=131691)
- [Primordial Ruby](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=131686)
- [Sun's Raidance](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=131695)
- [Vermilion Onyx](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=131690)
- [Wild Jade](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=131688)

You can also bypass the one-day cooldown by researching [Secrets of the Stone](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=131759). It, however, costs 3 [Spirit of Harmony](http://www.wowhead.com/item=76061), which is BoP and quite difficult to come by without farming for it specifically.

For meta gem recipes, you need to do dalies for the [Golden Lotus](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1269) faction. You will be awarded [Treasures of the Vale](http://www.wowhead.com/item=90625#contains), which has a chance of dropping Spirit of Harmony, one of these recipes and also the recipes for the [Jade Owl](http://www.wowhead.com/item=90470) and the [Sapphire Cub](http://www.wowhead.com/item=90471) (if you are a pet collector like myself).

The [Order of the Cloud Serpent](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1271) faction also offers mount recipes for jewelcrafters at Honored and Revered reputation.

The daily researches have no specific level requirement other than the one imposed upon leveling jewelcrafting. The ones that require you to complete quests with their corresponding factions are for 90's only.